# Firebase FCM push notifications not show on iOS 12

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am using python 3 and Django framework with Firebase FCM to send push notifications from an iOS device. The push notifications did not show on device, until yesterday.

When I now send a push notification, everything shows successful, but nothing is received on the device.

If I send directly via a curl request, this is the response:

{'failure': 0, 'canonical_ids': 0, 'success': 1, 'multicast_ids': [8348728835412078810], 'topic_message_id': None, 'results': [{'message_id': '0:1543820637538874%6467bacd6467abcd'}]}

If I send from the Notification dashboard on the firebase console, it shows successfully completed.

I have done the following with no success:

1. Locked in pod for, 'Firebase/Core' and 'Firebase/Messaging'.
2. Generated a new APN key on developer console and replaced the
   existing key on FCM setup in Firebase.
3. Downloaded a fresh GoogleService-Info.plist and replaced existing
4. Checked that bundle id's etc all match.
5. Updated firebase pods to latest versions
6. Turned message swizzling off in info.plist file  (i.e. FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled = No)
7. Setting Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
8. Made sure remote notification in Capabilities are still turned on

Comment: did you found a solution ?